# Как проверить правильность ввода содержимого TextBox?

Tags: winforms, .net, c++, visual-studio

Доброго времени суток!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как проверить правильность ввода значения double в TextBox (Visual Studio C++, проект Windows Form). При смене фокуса с TextBox, по этому значению строится график и если ввести букву или какой-нибудь бред, то программа вылетает.

Если можно, объясните подробней (новичек).

Comment: как решили проблему с вычислением произвольной функции ? или функция жестко задана, и меняете только пару коэффициентов ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете проверить строку в [момент приведения](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/994c0zb1.aspx) ее к значению double с помощью Double::TryParse

```
Double number = 0;
System::String^ str = "1.0";

if (Double::TryParse(str, number))
{
    // Успешно
}else{
    // Неуспешно
}
```